# In MATLAB how to get the result of a classification tree in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I made a Classification Tree, code:

```
mytree=ClassificationTree.fit(MyData,MyLables);
mytree.view('mode','graph');
```

My data has two classes and I want to get the result of prediction as a matrix that can show me every data row is belongs to which as an example.

```
data row          predicted class

1                   2
2                   1
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
```

how can i make this matrix?

---------------------Edited----------------------

I found that with this function I can predict my data:

label = predict(Mdl,MyData([1:50],:));

but this labels are belong to which rows?

Comment: Isn't predicted class the same as `MyLables`?

Comment: yes they are as the same

Comment: So what is the issue? is the issue generating the first column `data row`?

Comment: As of the edit, the labels obviously belong to 1 to 50 rows which you're inputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column, i.e. 'data row', is simply a vector starting from 1 to number of rows of `X` (which is obviously also the same as number of values in `Y`). The second column, i.e. 'predicted class', is the same as the variable `MyLables`. Hence:

```
ReqResult = [(1:numel(Y)).' Y];
%Assuming Y is a column vector (order = nx1). 
%If Y is a row vector then take the transpose of Y as well.
```

---

**Warning:**

If you're using ≥ R2014a, you should use [`fitctree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html) instead of [`ClassificationTree.fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationtree.fit.html)   because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationtree.fit.html):

> [`ClassificationTree.fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationtree.fit.html) will be removed in a future release. Use [`fitctree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html) instead.